# print_line must be declared pl/sql error

Tags: plsql

```
declare
test  varchar2(20);
BEGIN
    test := 'This is a test';
    dbms_output.print_line(test);
END;
/
```

I get `print_line` must be declared as error. This works fine from command line. But now when written in notepad and executed via

```
@ c:\pathtofile\test.txt
```

Comment: dbms_output doesn't have print_line subprogram. You don't show us the content of test.txt where you probably use an existing subprogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBMS_OUTPUT package doesn't have a print_line [subprogram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i999346). It's put_line & I suspect that's what is there under text file